# Pygame2Exe Errors that I can't fix

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, runtime-error, py2exe

I made a "Game". I love playing it, and I would like to distribute it to my friends without having to install Python and Pygame on their computers.

I did a lot of research on Py2Exe and Pyinstaller. I looked through many tutorials, fixes, errors, but none of them seem to help me.

Pyinstaller is useless because it doesn't like fonts in Pygame, and Py2exe wouldn't compile the built in modules, so I found Pygame2exe which is just a premade setup script for use with py2exe that includes pygame and fonts. It supposedly builds fine, but the exe is unusable... I get the error:

> "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
>
> Runtime Error!
>
> Program C:...\dist\Worm Game.exe
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual
>   way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information."

I just don't get it... Why can't I compile this game!!!

Here is the game code, made with Python 2.7:

```
import pygame
import random
import os

pygame.init()

class Worm:
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = surface.get_width() / 2
        self.y = surface.get_height() / 2
        self.length = 1
        self.grow_to = 50
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = -1
        self.body = []
        self.crashed = False
        self.color = 255, 255, 0

    def event(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            if self.vy != 1:
                self.vx = 0
                self.vy = -1
            else:
                a = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            if self.vy != -1:
                self.vx = 0
                self.vy = 1
            else:
                a = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            if self.vx != 1:
                self.vx = -1
                self.vy = 0
            else:
                a = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            if self.vx != -1:
                self.vx = 1
                self.vy = 0
            else:
                a = 1

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy
        if (self.x, self.y) in self.body:
            self.crashed = True
        self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y))
        if (self.grow_to > self.length):
            self.length += 1
        if len(self.body) > self.length:
            self.body.pop()

    def draw(self):
        x, y = self.body[0]
        self.surface.set_at((x, y), self.color)
        x, y = self.body[-1]
        self.surface.set_at((x, y), (0, 0, 0))

    def position(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    def eat(self):
        self.grow_to += 25

class Food:
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = random.randint(10, surface.get_width()-10)
        self.y = random.randint(10, surface.get_height()-10)
        self.color = 255, 255, 255

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, (self.x, self.y, 3, 3), 0)

    def erase(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, 3, 3), 0)

    def check(self, x, y):
        if x < self.x or x > self.x +3:
            return False
        elif y < self.y or y > self.y +3:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def position(self):
        return self.x, self.y

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
GameName = font.render("Worm Eats Dots", True, (255, 255, 0))
GameStart = font.render("Press Any Key to Play", True, (255, 255, 0))

w = 500
h = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))


GameLoop = True
while GameLoop:
    MenuLoop = True
    while MenuLoop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                MenuLoop = False
        screen.blit(GameName, (180, 100))
        screen.blit(GameStart, (155, 225))
        pygame.display.flip()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    score = 0
    worm = Worm(screen)
    food = Food(screen)
    running = True

    while running:
        worm.move()
        worm.draw()
        food.draw()

        if worm.crashed:
            running = False
        elif worm.x <= 0 or worm.x >= w-1:
            running = False
        elif worm.y <= 0 or worm.y >= h-1:
            running = False
        elif food.check(worm.x, worm.y):
            score += 1
            worm.eat()
            print "Score %d" % score
            food.erase()
            food = Food(screen)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                worm.event(event)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(200)

    if not os.path.exists("High Score.txt"):
        fileObject = open("High Score.txt", "w+", 0)
        highscore = 0
    else:
        fileObject = open("High Score.txt", "r+", 0)
        fileObject.seek(0, 0)
        highscore = int(fileObject.read(2))
    if highscore > score:
        a = 1
    else:
        fileObject.seek(0, 0)
        if score < 10:
            fileObject.write("0"+str(score))
        else:
            fileObject.write(str(score))
        highscore = score
    fileObject.close()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ScoreBoarda = font.render(("You Scored: "+str(score)), True, (255, 255, 0))
    if highscore == score:
        ScoreBoardb = font.render("NEW HIGHSCORE!", True, (255, 255, 0))
        newscore = 1
    else:
        ScoreBoardb = font.render(("High Score: "+str(highscore)), True, (255, 255, 0))
        newscore = 0
    Again = font.render("Again?", True, (255, 255, 0))
    GameOver = font.render("Game Over!", True, (255, 255, 0))
    screen.blit(GameName, (180, 100))
    screen.blit(GameOver, (200, 137))
    screen.blit(ScoreBoarda, (190, 205))
    if newscore == 0:
        screen.blit(ScoreBoardb, (190, 235))
    elif newscore == 1:
        screen.blit(ScoreBoardb, (175, 235))
    screen.blit(Again, (220, 365))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (200, 400, 40, 40), 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (260, 400, 40, 40), 0)
    LEFT = font.render("L", True, (0, 0, 0))
    RIGHT = font.render("R", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(LEFT, (215, 415))
    screen.blit(RIGHT, (275, 415))
    pygame.display.flip()
    loop = True
    while loop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x, y = event.pos
                if x > 200 and x < 240 and y > 400 and y < 440:
                    loop = False
                elif x > 260 and x < 300 and y > 400 and y < 440:
                    GameLoop = False
                    loop = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    loop = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    GameLoop = False
                    loop = False

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: If any other information is needed, just ask.

Comment: Also, I don't want someone to just compile this for me. I want to learn exactly what's wrong here so that I can recompile it in the future if I make any changes or if I make another game.

Comment: I've tried messing around with pyinstaller and pygame2exe some more, and no progress... Is anyone even reading these?

Comment: [Someone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018065/pygame-distribution-runtime-error) seems to have had the exact same problem earlier this year - though it is unclear how his problem was solved.

Comment: [This](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/560828-making-a-pygame-exe-with-py2exe/) might also be relevant.

Comment: Thank you, but I've already found and tried both of those. I wish I knew what Paul did to get his to work, as when I copied all of the listed dlls to the .exe folder, nothing was fixed. And I've already looked through the guide to distributing modules and programs, nothing in there helped... Unless I missed something...

Comment: Problem is still not fixed, fyi.

Answer (score 5):

I met this problem, too. After investigation, I found that the runtime error is caused by the font. I noticed that you also used None as the font name, too. Please remember that there's a notice for using the pygame2exe about the font, just below "Changes by arit:" at [pygame2exe page](http://pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe), that we should use a "fontname.ttf" to replace None and place that fontname.ttf under the correct folder that the exe can find. For example, you can use "freesansbold.ttf" to replace None when creating font, and place freesansbold.ttf under the folder the exe file exists. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is anything wrong with your code. Infact, it compiles well and I played as well. Nice game.

I would suggest looking into the following in your computer,

1. Have you installed all Microsoft Updates
2. Look through the programs ( Control Panel - Programs & Features) and see if you have the latest Microsoft Visual C++ Libraries are Present.

I think if the above two are properly in place, it should work fine.

I tested this on a machine with the following conf:
 1. Windows 7 with all the security patches updated.

Comment: I already had the latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redist. package up to date. But for some reason, I can't update my pc. "Windows Update cannot currently check for updates, because the service is not running. You may need to restart your computer." This continued after restarting... Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Comment: There could be several possibilities, I will look for the following 1. Firewall ( and all related stuff) 2. Check whether your antivirus or any other related software is blocking the updates. Also, I found this interesting link from MS Support team , have a look and see if that helps http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-cannot-currently-check-for-updates/b250e431-cdfc-46ac-a044-eaaee17491cf

Comment: "Click Start;
Type: cmd;
Right click on cmd in start menu and select 'Run as Administrator';
Type: net stop wuauserv;
Hit Enter;
Type: ren c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution softwaredistribution.old;
Hit Enter;
Type: net start wuauserv;
Hit Enter;
Type: exit;
Hit Enter"

I tried the beforehand approach, and was unsuccessful... I got an error saying "The service name is invalid." And Windows Defender isn't blocking the updates. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

After few weeks (had this problem even before) I'm happy to say that I solved this problem! :)

**1st part of my problem** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpkjR.png):
I solved it by editing setup.py script with adding "excludes" part in it. That resulted in successful making of executable file!

Modified setup.py script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=['source_static.py'], options={
          "py2exe": {
              "excludes": ["OpenGL.GL", "Numeric", "copyreg", "itertools.imap", "numpy", "pkg_resources", "queue", "winreg", "pygame.SRCALPHA", "pygame.sdlmain_osx"],
              }
          }
      )
```

So, if you have similar issues, just put those "missing" modules into this "excludes" line.

**2nd part:**

After I succeeded in making of executable file, I had next problem: *"**The application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in unusual way. Please contact...**"*. After days and days of searching and thinking how to solve this another problem, I found a way to do it. I couldn't believe that the problem was so absurd. The problem was in my code, with font definition:

```
font1 = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 13)
```

After changing "**None**" to some system font name (for an example "Arial" (must be a string)), and compiling, I couldn't believe that my .exe file worked!

```
font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 13)
```

Of course, you can use your own font, but you must specify its path and define it in your program.

So for all of you who are experiencing this issues, try this steps and I hope that you will succeed.
I really hope that this will help you, because I've lost days and weeks trying to solve these problems. I even tried making my .exe file with all versions of python and pygame, with many other .exe builders and setup scripts, but without luck. Besides these problems, I had many other problems before but I found answers to them on stackoverflow.com.

I'm happy that I found a way to solve this problems and to help you if you are faced with the same ones.

**Small tips (things I've also done):**

> > 1st: update your Microsoft Visual C++ library to the latest one.
> >
> > 2nd: if you have images or fonts similar that your executable program needs, include them to **dist** folder (where your .exe file has been created).
> >
> > 3rd: when you are making your .exe file, include all needed files to the folder where your setup.py script is (all files and directories that your main script uses).

Used **Python 2.7 x64**, **pygame** and **py2exe**.