# pygame2exe "Runtime Error! This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way..."

Tags: dll, pygame, py2exe

I've started making a game using python and pygame, and tried using py2exe. It didn't work, (like it should), so I used the pygame2exe code found here: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe

It still doesn't work, and comes up with the error stated in the title. I have a suspicion it's to do with not having the correct dlls, but I'm clueless apart from that.

Also, I managed to create a pygame executable in what I think was exactly the same way a few months ago, but now it doesn't work. If you'd like me o add a little more info I'd be happy to.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9ZyR.jpg) a screenshot of the error message (I can't post images yet):

Comment: Have you tried the solution proposed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826093/pygame2exe-errors-that-i-cant-fix)?

Comment: sorry I didn't reply, I actually didn't see this response until just now for some reason... After having just googled to try and find the solution, I ran into this question thinking it wasn't mine... Well at least I've got your reply now! Anyway, I hadn't taken a look at that question, thanks for linking me to it. I think I tried messing around with stuff to do with the fonts, but not that in particular...

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem and I finally solved it. The problem is with my font definition:

```
    basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
    overFont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 60)
```

Using a default font to replace 'None' in your definition and add '.ttf' files in your dist folder can help